# LoggingSelenium for HTML tests?

Tags: logging, selenium, selenium-rc

Currently, I'm running selenium HTML tests like this:

`java -jar scripts/selenium-server-standalone-2.4.0.jar -browserSessionReuse -htmlSuite *firefox $targetServer ./test/selenium/html/TestSuite.html ./target/selenium/html/TestSuiteResults.html`

[LoggingSelenium](http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/) looks pretty interesting, but I don't see how to use it with the standalone driver. Is there a way I can get things like screenshots of test failures or logging of the current-test running with just the standalone driver and a HTML TestSuite?